# Loading multiple rows from single column using SQL Loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a requirement where I need to load data from datafile into table using SQL loader. However the data will be provided in a single line for similar channels. ROW_ID is the primary key and is being generated using a sequence. IDENTIFY is an internal channel identifier. IDENTIFY cannot be the primary key as it would defy first normal form. Below is the data file :

```
IDENTIFY|CHANNEL_NAME|CHANNEL_PARTNERS                                                  |LOAD_DATE
1-ED    |WEBSITE     |"redbus","abhibus","amazon travel","irctc"                        |02-FEB-2022
1-LP    |WALKIN      |"physical reservation","printed reservation","current reservation"|04-FEB-2022
```

However the data to be loaded into database is like this using SQLLDR.

```
IDENTIFY   CHANNEL_NAME   CHANNEL_PARTNERS     LOAD_DATE
1-ED       WEBSITE        redbus               02-FEB-2022
1-ED       WEBSITE        abhibus              02-FEB-2022
1-ED       WEBSITE        amazon travel        02-FEB-2022
1-ED       WEBSITE        irctc                02-FEB-2022
1-LP       WALKIN         physical reservation 04-FEB-2022
1-LP       WALKIN         printed reservation  04-FEB-2022
1-LP       WALKIN         current reservation  04-FEB-2022
```

Below is the CTL file.

```
load data 
infile 'mchannel.txt'
append into table master_channel
fields terminated by "|"
(
 row_id  "chan_seq.nextval",
 identify,
 channel_name,
 channel_partners,
 load_date
)
```

How can I achieve this using SQLLDR ?

Comment: But you've already asked this question resently... Did you try suggestions from it?

Comment: We already saw this question, you seem to be asking the same thing again. You can do this with some fancy SQL*Loader logic (multiple INTO clauses and careful WHEN tests with dummy cols), but if it were me, I'd just run the data through a simple awk program to unfold the repeating group into one line per channel_partner. and then load that directly.

Comment: As for your PK, sure you could use a sequence-generated surrogate, but you could also more simply just make it (identify,channel_partner)

Answer (score 0):

You firstly can create a subsidiary table

```
CREATE TABLE master_channel_
(                                                                                                                                                                
 identify           VARCHAR2(15),
 channel_names      VARCHAR2(25), 
 channel_partners   VARCHAR2(500),
 load_date          VARCHAR2(25)  
);
```

and load data into it by

```bash
$ . mchannel.sh
```

where its content is

```bash
sqlldr userid="un/pwd"@thedb control=mchannel.ctl log=mchannel.log bad=mchannel.bad errors=99999999 direct=y
```

and .ctl file is

```bash
OPTIONS(skip=1)
LOAD DATA                                                                                                                                                                           
 INFILE 'mchannel.txt' "str '\n'"                                                                                                           
 TRUNCATE INTO TABLE master_channel_                                                                                                                      
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'                                                                                                                                                         
 (                                                                                                                                                                
  identify           CHAR(15)  "TRIM(:identify)",
  channel_names      CHAR(25)  "TRIM(:channel_names)", 
  channel_partners   CHAR(500) "TRIM(:channel_partners)",
  load_date          CHAR(25)  "TRIM(:load_date)"
 )
```

then use the following query

```
INSERT INTO master_channel(identify,channel_names,channel_partners,load_date)
 SELECT m.identify,
        m.channel_names,
        TRIM( BOTH '"' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(m.channel_partners,'[^,]+',1,level)),
        TO_DATE(m.load_date,'dd-MON-yyyy')
   FROM master_channel_ m
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(m.channel_partners,',')+1
    AND prior sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
    AND prior m.identify = m.identify;
```

to insert into the main table while applying needed conversions, where the table is assumed to be created as

```
CREATE TABLE master_channel
(                          
 row_id             NUMBER generated always as identity,                                                                                                                                      
 identify           VARCHAR2(15),
 channel_names      VARCHAR2(25), 
 channel_partners   VARCHAR2(500),
 load_date          DATE  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Paul W suggested, a simple AWK do the job to prepare the file, and you can take opportunity to remove the double quotes (and/or change the separator, as you like):

```
awk -F '|' '{split($3,a,/,/)}; { for (s in a) { print $1 "|" $2 "|" substr( a[s], 2, length(a[s])-2 ) "|" $4 }  }' 


1-ED|WEBSITE|abhibus|02-FEB-2022
1-ED|WEBSITE|amazon travel|02-FEB-2022
1-ED|WEBSITE|irctc|02-FEB-2022
1-ED|WEBSITE|redbus|02-FEB-2022
1-LP|WALKIN|printed reservation|04-FEB-2022
1-LP|WALKIN|current reservation|04-FEB-2022
1-LP|WALKIN|physical reservation|04-FEB-2022
```